# Imposible recuperar el valor del índice 0 de una tupla: <class 'TypeError'> en Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Me enfrento con el siguiente problema, espero puedan echarme una mano.

**CONTEXTO.** Python 3.9.1, MySQL 5.7.24. Windows 10

**QUÉ QUIERO HACER.** Quiero recuperar un registro de la base de datos y leer cada uno de sus datos (id, nombre, etc)

**PROBLEMA.** Recupero satisfactoriamente el registro de la BD con todos sus campos, incluyendo el ID. Sin problema puedo sacar e imprimir cada uno de los datos (nombre, email, etc). Pero por alguna razón, aunque el ID está presente en el registro devuelto, me es imposible sacarlo e imprimirlo. Cuando intento hacerlo obtengo una excepción: `<class 'TypeError'>`

**QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
sessionDB = Session()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    nombre = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    contrasena = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(255), default=datetime.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(255), default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


@app.route('/acceso', methods=['POST'])
def acceso():

    email = request.form['email']

    usuario = sessionDB.query(User.id, User.nombre, User.email, User.contrasena).filter(
        User.email == email
    ).first()

    print(usuario)
    # Output: (3, 'Juán', 'juan@gmail.com', '$2b$12$XQIw')
    # Como se ve, el índice 0 es el ID (el 3), ¡ahí está pero no puedo sacarlo!

    if usuario:
        db_id = 'null'
        db_nombre = 'null'
        db_email = 'null'
        db_pass = 'null'

        for indice, valor in enumerate(usuario):
            if indice == 0: # Esta línea provoca la excepción
                db_id = valor
            elif indice == 1:
                db_nombre = valor
            elif indice == 2:
                db_email = valor
            elif indice == 3:
                db_pass = valor
```

**CÓMO HE INTENTADO SOLUCIONAR**
Probé cambiando la query a esto:

```
usuario = sessionDB.query(User).filter(
    User.email == email
).first()
```

Y el problema es el mismo si intento sacar el ID con:

```
print(usuario.id)
```

Comment: `usuario[0]` es todo lo que necesitas

Comment: Gracias, @Christian, ooops! Tienes razón, sí funciona con usuario[0]. Pero la verdad que sí me extraña mucho por qué salta excepción si intento hacerlo de las otras formas mencionadas.